# Is there a format where I can transfer data with Spring Rest without serialization/deserialization

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have some workflows in my application where I am requesting data and it gets serialized and deserialized several times on the way back to the user interface.  The number of services that the data passes through is necessary, and I am unlikely to be able to change the architecture of the workflows.  Is there any data format that I can use as a pass-through so that the data is not repeatedly serialized/deserialized as it progresses through the workflow?  For example, if I convert it to a byte array after the data is retrieved by the data layer, or assembled via some other process, can I instruct Spring to leave it as-is and not incur the penalty of repeated marshaling and unmarshaling?

Comment: Sure, of course. return or accept byte arrays, and no serialization/deserializaton will be necessary.

Comment: @JBNizet if you post this as an answer, I will accept it.  I realize it's pretty old, but I will still give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jb-nizet said, simply return or accept byte arrays to avoid serialization and deserialization.